# wanna enable audit diagnostics settings of aks node resource group resources NSG and virtual machine scale set using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I am able to enable audit diagnostic settings for aks using arm(below snippet inside arm )but the same way have enable the same in all resources in node resource group like network security group and vitual machine scale set.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[parameters('audit_enable')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[clustername]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters', clutername)]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "storageAccountId": "[variables('storageAccountId')]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 30,
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "category": "AllMetrics",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 30,
              "enabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below statements are based on our observations & Azure Documentations. We have tested in our local environment by creating a virtual machine scale set & tried enabling the diagnostic setting for it Unfortunately we dont have diagnostics setting feature for virtual machine scale sets.

**Here is the output screenshot for reference:**

[image]

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/monitor-virtual-machine#agents), Azure Diagnostics agent is available for virtual Machine only.

Azure Diagnostics [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agents-overview#azure-diagnostics-extension) collects monitoring data from the guest operating system and workloads of Azure virtual machines and other compute resources. It primarily collects data into Azure Storage but also allows you to define data sinks to also send data to other destinations such as Azure Monitor Metrics and Azure Event Hubs.

Here is the reference documentation to create the diagnostics setting for a virtual machine using [arm template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json#add-the-azure-diagnostics-extension-to-the-vm-resource-definition).

We tried searching for sample arm templates to create the diagnosticsetting for network security group unfortunately we didnt found any Would suggest you to go this documentation of [basic arm template to create the diagnostic settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/diagnosticsettings?tabs=json) & make the changes accordingly to your requirement.

You can also refer the [ARM templates samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings) for diagnostic settings in Azure monitor.